# ASUS Q502L “no battery detected” - Windows 8.1

Tags: bios, battery, uefi

**PLEASE NOTE:: There is a fair possibility that I have found a solution to this quite some time ago, I continuously attempt to post a solution, but for some reason a moderator is persistently deleting it - for reasons that I cannot understand. With that said, I cannot make any promises, but please feel free to PM me and I would be glad to assist in fixing. 20161205**

I bought the specified model about one month ago. I immediately upgraded HDD to SSD and my system seemed to work fine for three weeks. I left my computer in my car one morning, and when I tried to use my computer that following night, it would not charge. It only works when plugged in. I do not know if this is due to heat or something that went wrong post-migration to SSD.

The battery icon on the bottom right usually has "no battery detected." However, I have seen it say "battery connected, but not charging" and "plugged in and not charging." The two first mentioned quotes come paired with a red "X" next to the battery icon. For the last quote, the red X is replaced by a white picture of a power plug.

I am hoping that this is something that is related to the BIOS settings, however my computer uses UEFI and I am unaware how to check if the battery is connected through there. Could you please tell me how I can check if my battery is connected, or how I can determine if this is a hardware issue (i.e. the battery/motherboard became damaged due to heat in my car) or something related to the BIOS/UEFI/I/O  settings?

Really, ANY advice, navigation, or explanations are much obliged. Thank you

This is bothering me quite a bit, as this laptop is still brand new to me and I am only able to use it when plugged in. I am thankful, though, at it at least still functions.

If you have any questions, please ask.

P.S. BIOS mode is UEFI (don't know exactly what that means) & (COPY::)

BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. Q502LAB.205, 12/12/2014
SMBIOS Version  2.8

I also found two interesting indicators, highlighted in pink, via the command prompt via powercfg -batteryreport, which is as follows;

"Battery:Battery Capacity Unknown
The battery capacity could not be determined. This may indicate a firmware (BIOS) problem.
Battery ID
Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled
PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to a known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer."

The last interesting thing I would like to share is the information contained under "Battery:Battery Information" in the same report:

"Battery:Battery Information
Battery ID
Manufacturer
Serial Number
Chemistry
Long Term   1
Sealed  0
Design Capacity 
Last Full Charge"

This was very strange to me, as no information seemed available with regard to the battery.

Please help, thank you so much in advance

Comment: It is possible , but not very likely that in extreeme heat conditions a non-resettable thermal fuse that will exist in well made battery packs would open up and disable the battery from further use. The temperaure in the car would have to be so high that you could not touch the steering wheel at first, plus additional heat would have to exist like Direct sun , and/or charging the battery at the same time. The themal fuse is at a temperature setting that is only a safety factor for a battery heating to the point of venting, or self igniting. Most other safety and operation things will reset.

Comment: The battery and how it connects to the rest of the machine, could be checked with a simple voltmeter, simple continuity tests could be done. But that battery is not easily user accessable?  (non-removable).  It could easily be other issues, i am not suggesting that it is the battery for sure.

Comment: I live in Las Vegas, Nevada. This is a very hot city and I believe that in a stagnant vehicle it could become up to 180 Fahrenheit (I think,) does that sound like a drastic enough temperature?

Comment: Wow, you should of mentioned this as the main point in your post. That temperature can do that to your battery easily no matter how "new" it is.

Comment: So it is possible that I must buy a new battery?

Comment: Once you got to the battery, it would be easy to test it, and it is fairly easy to find where the power stops at, and see (first) if there is a thermal protection fuse, and replace the fuse. While doing that if the battery was showing signs of bulging/puffing then you would replace it. If the device is fairly new, and the battery was still ok, whatever connection problem it has (maybe is isnt a fuse thing) the battery would not nessisarily be replaced. Anyone would can replace the battery easily, could probably also repair a connection issue,

Comment: Wow, you really know your stuff. 
So my first line of action will be to gain access to the battery and just check for puffiness/bulging (if the battery has those indications then it could be as simple as replacing the battery) and if not then I will check all lines connected the battery to the motherboard using a voltmeter and also check the thermal protection fuse to see if it is still good. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at the documentation, it seems like the battery is internal. I'll assume you laptop model is Q502LA. There are a few options you can try.

### Battery Status Indicator

First please check the battery status indicator on the front side of your laptop. It is the indicator in the middle. It can be one of the following light status: Solid Green, Solid Orange, Blinking Orange, or Lights Off.

Based on the battery status indicator we can gain extra information about the status of the battery.

### Drive Reinstall

If that does not work out, we can try to reinstall the *Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery* driver. To do this, do the following:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Expand the Battery category and Right Click > Uninstall the *Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery* listing.
3. Click the Scan for Hardware (last one to the right) button in the taskbar.

### Flashing the BIOS

If that does not fix the problem, you can try flashing your BIOS.

To flash you follow the simple instructions in the [user manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N542LA/0409_E8878_B.pdf) on page 85.  Assuming an Intel Core i5 CPU and model Q502LA You can download the BIOS VERSION 207 [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Q502LAB/Q502LABAS207.zip).

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you. The light in the front of the laptop is a blinking orange light when plugged in

Does this mean anything in particular in my situation? I will follow your instructions after I determine what this blinking light means

Comment: "The Notebook PC is running on battery mode and the battery power is less than 10%." You still have the charger connected, correct? So the hardware also recognizes that the battery is there but it is not charging. The driver reinstall part will probably not work but you can still try it. Flashing the BIOS might do it.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know how that goes. Currently the batter icon says "no battery is detected" with a red X.

Yes, the power cord is connected. It only turns on or gives any LED signals when it is plugged in

Comment: Please also keep in mind of the comment on the actual post regarding your battery.

Comment: The bios update is on my flash drive now. when I enter my flash drive from UEFI, I see just every file that my flash drive has except for the BIOS file. Is this because that file is the only zip file?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad question. I simply removed to document from that file and performed the BIOS update. Which, was unsuccessful to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

So, after months of trying to figure this out myself - without taking it into a shop - I figured out the extremely simple solution to this. I am going to post this answer to all other threads that I have posted with regard to this, just in case somebody else has a similar issue regarding a like-modeled laptop. I'm not saying that this is a universal solution, but it is one that worked for me and was so simple that I simply overlooked it.

The connections between many of the hardware components of this laptop are extremely delicate and connect by nothing more than an adhesive and a small piece of black tape. With my situation having been that I left my computer in a hot car for too long, I assumed that it was heat damage to the battery and I would need a replacement. I took the back off of my computer yesterday for fun (I'll post a video at the end of this that shows a person I do not know disassembling a very similar computer if you need help) in an attempt to view the cpu. While doing this I decided it would be a good idea to remove the - in the words of an Asus rep from a phone call I made - "not removable battery" from the system so that I could take note of the model number. In doing so, it was then that I learned about the weak adhesive tape. I realized that the battery seemed to be partially disconnected, presumably because the heat of the car softened the adhesive and the connection shifted. I reconnected the battery and reassembled the computer and fired her up. Then, BAM! The battery worked WITHOUT the charger! How happy I must have been, until I realized the screen would not fire up. So I panicked, thinking that I broke it while taking it apart. I went back into the computer again and realized that the connection from the touch screen to the motherboard crossed over the connection to the battery and used the same weak adhesive and little back tape. I inspected and saw that it was peeled up slightly. This told that while I was handling the battery, I accidentally moved that chord. I reconnected/retaped it down and fired of the computer. Voila.

Thanks everybody for the help, I really appreciate it. And I'm glad that I got this fixed.

Here is the link to this taking it apart. This isn't me, and if you're careful you wont break the clips like he did... https://youtu.be/PjCtMtTdB7Q

Take care!